# AngularJS watcher in constructor not fired while testing

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, angular-services, angularjs-watch

I created a factory which returns a constructor. The constructor includes a watcher looking at a property of the instance. When that property is changed in tests, the watcher is not fired. Outside of tests, it is fired. $rootScope.$apply doesn't seem to help.

Here is a jsfiddle which contains a simplified version of my code and tests.

http://jsfiddle.net/2Ny8x/234/

```
//--- CODE --------------------------
(function (angular) {
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.factory('MyObject', function($rootScope) {
        function MyObject() {
            this.prop = 5;
            this.watcherCallback = angular.noop;

            $rootScope.$watch(this.prop, this.watcherCallback);
        }

        return MyObject;
    });
})(angular);


// ---SPECS-------------------------
describe('MyObject', function () {
    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    var MyObject, rootScope;
    beforeEach(inject(function (_MyObject_, $rootScope) {
        MyObject = _MyObject_;
        rootScope = $rootScope;
    }));

    it('calls the watcher when "prop" updates', function() {
        var newObj = new MyObject();
        spyOn(newObj, 'watcherCallback');

        newObj.prop = 10;
        rootScope.$apply();

        expect(newObj.watcherCallback).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Why doesn't the watcher fire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var newObj = new MyObject();
```

This assigns `noop` to `newObj.watcherCallback`. And it registers `newObj.watcherCallback` (so, `noop`) as a watcher caallback.

```
spyOn(newObj, 'watcherCallback');
```

This replaces `newObj.watcherCallback` by another function, which allows you to know when this new spy function is called. But it doesn't register this spy function as a watcher callback to the rootScope. What is register is the original one: `noop`.

So, when you change the value of the property and call `$apply()`, the rootScope still has a reference to the `noop` function and calls it. Your spy is unaware of it.

It should work fine if you do in the constructor:

```
var that = this;
$rootScope.$watch(this.prop, function() {
    that.watcherCallback();
});
```